# adding domain name and mx records for mail only in directadmin

Tags: email, dns, directadmin

I am quite new to webadmin (esp email setups), and I am in the process of setting up emails for an app (mydomain.com) which is hosted elsewhere (a VPS provider via cloudflare dns)

I have a small shared hosting plan with directadmin acces with another provider, and I am wondering as to how I set up an email only system for my app (which is hosted elsewhere), with this shared hosting provider.

My questions are:

[1] Do I simply point the MX record for the domain (in cloudflare) to the shared hosting IP address and create the email addresses with directadmin?

[2] Do I need to add my domain name in directadmin? or do I add mail.mydomain.com?

Any help or pointers to this will be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, Yes. You need to point the MX Record to the shared hosting IP and create the email adres in directadmin

[2] If you want to use you domain for the email then you need to add the domain indeed. After that you can add custom email prefixes (**info**@example.com) to that domain.

For more information about this you can always read:
http://www.site-helper.com/